# Kubuntu 16.10 slow start up

Tags: kubuntu

My `systemmd-analyse blame`result is terrifying, and I wonder what can I do to minimise the start up time.

```
 30.307s apt-daily.service
     10.945s dev-sda2.device
     10.103s keyboard-setup.service
      6.508s systemd-udevd.service
      4.121s tor@default.service
      3.866s NetworkManager.service
      3.666s ModemManager.service
      3.629s accounts-daemon.service
      3.277s snapd.firstboot.service
      3.117s thermald.service
      2.499s gpu-manager.service
      2.219s ofono.service
      2.105s rsyslog.service
      1.759s avahi-daemon.service
      1.733s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.549s networking.service
      1.081s grub-common.service
      1.033s rtkit-daemon.service
       950ms apparmor.service
       859ms systemd-modules-load.service
       787ms dev-hugepages.mount
       784ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       783ms dev-mqueue.mount
       765ms apport.service
       762ms wpa_supplicant.service
       711ms upower.service
       708ms irqbalance.service
       509ms plymouth-quit.service
       494ms setvtrgb.service
       493ms systemd-logind.service
       442ms lm-sensors.service
       417ms binfmt-support.service
       387ms systemd-journald.service
       383ms polkitd.service
       313ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       308ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6445\x2dCA3D.service
       304ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       292ms user@1000.service
       282ms ufw.service
       279ms packagekit.service
       269ms systemd-sysctl.service
       263ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       250ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       237ms user@121.service
       220ms plymouth-start.service
       218ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       214ms pppd-dns.service
       214ms systemd-resolved.service
       190ms bluetooth.service
       187ms udisks2.service
```